# backup files smaller than 100 KB

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted to backup all the files that are smaller than 100 KB in my home directory, and keep the file structure (the folder tree) and timestamp during the backup. How could I achieve this in Linux? Thanks very much!

Comment: you can try `rsync` with the option `--max-size=100000` (and `-a`).

Comment: That's amazing! I didn't know this option before. Thank you @gniourf_gniourf

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You should post that as an answer as a reference for others. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good strategy is to use `rsync`. This little utility is amazingly versatile, and, of course, well adapted to backups. The key, here, for your requirements of including only the files with a maximum size of 100kB is to use the `--max-size` option:

```
rsync -a --max-size=100kB sourcedir destdir
```

The `-a` option will preserve your timestamps too (and invoke recursion, copy symlinks, preserve permissions, groups and owner (if it has the permission)). Read the manual, you might find that it has other options you absolutely need!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
find /usr/mydir -type f -size -1000 -print0 | tar --null --no-recursion -cjf backup.tar.bz2 --files-from -
```

This will read all files up to 1000 bytes starting from /usr/mydir and add those to a newly created archive called "backup.tar.bz2".

**find options:**

-type f: just files

-size -1000: less than 1000 bytes (+1000: more than 1000 bytes)
-print0: just print the file name

**tar options:**

--null --file-from: read names from stdin
--no-recursion: don't recursively search the passed paths
--cjf {file}: create bzip2 archive (c: create, j: bzip2: f: filename)

(uses gnu tar version, IIRC)